# Can't finish GitHub sharing process- Error message

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I made a project called "Tip Calculator" on Android studio using Kotlin and wanted to share it on Github so I did an Initial Commit and proceeded to share.

I already ran `git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"` and also
`git config --global user.email myemailadress@gmail.com` Then, when I shared it, it is giving me this error message-

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
    Successfully created project 'TipCalculator' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
                Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected end of file from server
                at git4idea.GitAppUtil.sendXmlRequest(GitAppUtil.java:30)
                at git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:58)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
                at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:866)
                at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
                at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:863)
                at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
                at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
                at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection... (show balloon)
```

I really want to share my project on Github, please give a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are not used for authentication. It's not clear what went wrong during the `git push` step from the above, except that apparently Android Studio is not actually using Git (it seems to be using JGit instead).

Comment: so... should I try another commit or what?

Comment: I don't know, but I added the android-studio tag so that you are asking those who have used android-studio (which, if it's not the *source* of the problem, is definitely *involve in* the problem). If there's no reason that you *have* to use android-studio itself, perhaps you could use regular Git commands, which might (or might not!) be more informative.